# OCMock 3 Partial Mock: Class methods and the objc runtime

Tags: ocmock

I'm running into an interesting issue when using OCMock 3 when partially mocking an object that defines class methods.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with the dynamic subclassing that takes part as partial mocking or my misunderstanding of the objc runtime.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As part of running tests and other debug builds we do some runtime verification of method declarations using OmniFoundations' OBRuntimeCheck.  One of these checks, in short, attempts to use the runtime to verify that type signatures match for class methods across inheritance and protocol conformance.  This happens by listing the classes registered in the runtime and for each class the instance methods of the `metaClass` are copied.  For each `Method` from the metaClass if it exists on the metaClass's superclass the type signatures are compared.

The problem comes when calling class_getInstanceMethod on the metaClass's superclass for one of the ocmock replacement selectors, `ocmock_replaced_*`.  The test crashes `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code=EXC_i386_INVOP subcode=0x0` and `no class for metaclass` is logged in the console. Example given:

```
class_getInstanceMethod(metaSuperClass, NSSelectorFromString(@"ocmock_replaced_classMessage"))
```

When partial mocking an object that defines a class method, it appears that the OCMock 3 framework generates a dynamic subclass, does some isa swizzling of the mocked object and also some isa swizzling of the dynamically generated class' metaClass.

This behavior and crash is new in OCMock 3 and I'm really at a loss of where to look next.  Any runtime gurus have any idea what may be going on here?  When looking through the code it did surprise me that the dynamically generated class used for the mock was having it's meta class swizzled out, but I don't necessarily think that is wrong.  For ease in debugging I have created a simplified test case in a fresh fork of OCMock.  The crashing test can be found [here](https://github.com/NextThought/ocmock/commit/d0f204d82a01f811d3519b1e66ffdbb7871c4ce2).  Any help for guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be way off here, but I thought the superclass of a metaClass is NSObject (which is why you can normally call NSObject instance methods on class objects).  I'm not sure you should be doing anything, normally, with the superclass of a metaClass.

In general, the metaClass stores all of the information about class methods.  Therefore, getting an "instance" method on a metaClass is the same as getting a class method on the associated regular Class.  The runtime can simply dereference the "isa" pointer of an instance to find a method list to find instance methods; doing the same on a Class object gets the meta class (of the same structure) and therefore the same process results in finding the class methods.

OCMock will create a magic subclass for any partial mock, and change the class on that instance to the new subclass, so all the instance method swizzling will be specific to that instance.  For class methods though, I thought it had to modify the original class itself -- otherwise, calls to the regular class method in regular code would not be intercepted.  It keeps a copy of the original implementation so that when you call -stopMocking on the mock it can restore the original implementation (the added ocmock_replaced* impl will still be there but should no longer be called).

You could simply ignore any selector which starts with "ocmock_replaced" since that really is not related to your actual code you are presumably checking.  You might also have better luck changing "class_getInstanceMethod(metaSuperClass, ..." to "class_getClassMethod(regularSuperClass, ...").  I'm not sure why you would be getting a crash though -- I would expect class_getInstanceMethod(metaSuperClass, ...) to just return NULL in most situations.

Comment: Thanks, I can ignore selectors with the "ocmock_replaced" prefix but I am really hoping to understand the crash.  The reason for class_getInstanceMethod over class_getClassMethod is that this is in shared code called once with the object to verify instance methods, and a second time with the class to verify class methods. It looks like as part of the partial mock being applied, ocmock is swizzling out the metaClass of the mock object with the metaClass of the dynamically generated subclass used for the mock.  I'm wondering if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Lindeberg interestingly enough the object I am partial mocking is an instance of `OCMockObjectWithClassMessage`.  When I look at the metaClass of that after partially mocking an instance of that class the metaClass is the generated OCMock class `OCMockObjectWithClassMessage-0x105010f98-497779155`.  When I get the superclass of that metaClass (what I call metaSuperClass) I get back `OCMockObjectWithClassMessage`.

Comment: From looking at ObjC runtime source, that error message is when the runtime is presented with a meta class but it cannot find the associated regular class object.  That can happen if you forget to registerClassPair() after creating a new runtime class, but OCMock appears to do that correctly.  Normally, a Class object's isa pointer is the meta class.  How are you obtaining the metaSuperClass pointer?  Either there is something weird with the pointers or runtime, or the pointer in that case is not really valid.  I would not expect any ocmock_replaced methods to exist in superclasses.

Comment: I get the metaClass and metaSuperClass on lines 164 and 167 of [this commit](https://github.com/NextThought/ocmock/commit/d0f204d82a01f811d3519b1e66ffdbb7871c4ce2).  Essentially metaClass is obtained by calling object_getClass on the class my partial mock was created with, and then metaSuperClass is obtained by calling class_getSuperclass on metaClass.  Appreciate you helping me dig into this. @CarlLindberg

Comment: Hm, yeah, looking at OCClassMockObject, he is playing games with the meta classes, probably to avoid having the ocmock_replaced implementations remain in the regular class.  That is probably the root of the issue.   That was a change from OCMock 2.x which I'm more familiar with.  Still, the class is registered properly, so I'd have guessed the runtime could figure out the class given the meta class.  But I don't completely understand the structure he is now using.

Comment: I don't think class_getSuperclass(metaClass) is a good idea.  You might try class_getClass(class_getSuperclass(cls)) instead (i.e. get the regular superclass, then get its meta).  But his structure might have the meta class for the mock subclass and the meta class for the regular class be the same pointer, which can be confusing.  So he basically creates a custom subclass to store his mocked methods, changes the target class' isa (i.e. metaClass) to be the same one as the subclass, so that while in that state methods the sub-metaClass becomes the class methods for the regular class).

Comment: In that state, the substituted metaClass for the real class has no relation to the class (or metaclass) of the partial mock instance, as there are two runtime classes involved.  That could cause "interesting" issues with code which expects a regular structure, and you could be running into that.

Comment: Interesting. That fixes my test I wrote (both the crash and the assert that was failing in an unexpected way). `class_getClass(class_getSuperclass(cls)) ` is easier to follow.  I think OBRuntimeChecks are calling class_getSuperclass on the metaClass as as part of a generalization.  I'm not sure I can declaratively state what or where the bug is.  I guess I'll probably patch the runtime checks.  As far as I know (which is just enough to be dangerous), OCM isn't doing anything explicitly invalid with the runtime, however I can make an argument that the runtime checks are semantically incorrect.

Comment: So, I haven't had a chance to look into this more deeply. However, I can say that the swizzling of the meta class is not restricted to partial mocks, it also occurs on normal (class-based) mocks. The reason is, as Carl suspected, to make cleaning up easier, and to make verify-after-running possible on a per-class basis. Could you see whether you can create this problem with normal mocks, too?

Comment: I think the issue is that when you have a partial mock, you create a runtime subclass and change the instance's class to that.  Which is fine -- that subclass has its own metaclass, which inherits from the metaclass of the original.  But then a class method on the original is also mocked, which means you create a new subclass of the original, and change the original class' metaclass to the new one.  This works fine at runtime (the partial mock is only for instance methods, the other only for class methods) but if code tries to walk superclasses using that metaclass structure it ends in tears.

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg I can recreate the crash with a normal class mock.  A test demonstrating this crash can be found in [testRuntimeInspectialOfMockedClassMessage here](https://github.com/NextThought/ocmock/commit/c5eb4547eae3829f467f3f0a5adaee675de554dc).  In both cases (partial and class mock) if I do `class_getClass(class_getSuperclass(cls))` instead of `class_getSuperclass(metaClass)` things seem fine.  I think this may just be a case of another library making a bad assumption about relationships in the class and metaClass heirarchy.

Comment: Yeah, in that situation, the original class plus the new magic subclass are both pointing to the same metaclass (the one from the new subclass).  That will work fine for normal method calls since the magic subclass isn't used at all for instance methods, but can confuse things if you try to do operations directly on the metaClass (not normally recommend, especially with class structure).  The "super metaClass" is actually the one which has been temporarily removed from the runtime.  So, I would always walk class structures using the regular class, then get associated metaClass if needed.

Comment: In this situation, the isa (i.e. metaClass) of both the mockedClass and the new dynamic subclass is the same pointer.  I think that is confusing some of the ObjC runtime methods which try to get back to the original Class object from the metaClass, since that is ambiguous in this situation.  I tried replacing the superclass member of the subclass' metaClass to the one from the original metaClass, and that avoids the crash -- but breaks lots of OCMock unit tests.  So I think the runtime in this state is fragile, though it works for message passing.  Just avoid getSuperclass on a metaClass.